# Is there a way to override a symbol's color in Sketch?

Tags: color, sketch-app, symbols

I've already tried to to make symbols in sketch, like buttons, but I'm unable to change this symbol's colors, then I have to create more symbols only to change the color.

Do you guys know a way to change the color using only one symbol?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this question? I'm kind of looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good post about nested symbols: https://medium.com/@FreeAndWilling/sketch-tint-icons-using-nested-symbols-2d52867e0d29#.3fmmzviol